# delete alternate nodes in linked list in java

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am writing code for deleteing alternate nodes in linked list. why it goes in infinite loop ?
Input : 5->11->13->12->15->5 
Expected op : 5->13->15->5

```
public Node deleteAlternate(Node head)
{
    Node p = head;
    Node q = head.next;

    while(q!=null && q.next !=null)
    {
        p.next = q.next;
        q.next = p ;
        p.next = q;

        System.out.println(p.data+"   "+q.data);
    }
    return head;
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there are several points, some tips:

- Keep the code/logic simple. No loop with two variables and two conditions if not needed. And here you are walking linearly.
- The loop condition (on `q`) must be altered, so `q` must walk.
- Debug, or even better do it on paper first.

So something like:

```
public Node deleteAlternate(Node head)
{
    Node p = head;
    while (p != null) {
        if (p.next != null) {
            p.next = ... // delete the next.
        }
        p = p.next;
    }
    return head; // head is never deleted.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void DeleteAlternateNodes(Node head) {
    Node current=head;
    Node prev=head;
    if(head==null)
        return;
    else if(current.next==null)
        return;
    while(current!=null && current.next!=null)
    {
        prev.next=current.next.next;
        current=current.next;
        prev=prev.next;
    }
}
```

DeleteAlternateNodes(head);

I/P:5 10 15 25 35 25 40 O/P:5 15 35 40

Answer (score 0):

```
 /**
 *
 * Input : 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
 * Output : 1 -> 3 -> 5
 *
 * Input : 1
 * Output : 1
 *
 * Input : 1 -> 2
 * Output : 1
 *
 * Input : null
 * Output : null
 *
 */

public Node deleteAlternateNodes(Node<T> head) {
    Node<T> newHead = head;
    Node nextNode = null;
    while(head != null && head.next != null) {
        nextNode = head.next;
        head.next = nextNode.next;
        head = head.next;
    }
    return newHead;
}
```